# Amazon S3 Displaying Video From URL in React Native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, expo, aws-amplify

I have videos stored in a protected bucket on S3. I am able to retrieve the URLs in my React Native application using Amplify:

```
Storage.get(route.params.organizerVideoS3Keys, { level: "protected"})
          .then((result) => {
            console.log("result", result);
            setOrganizerVideo(result);
          })
```

However, when I put this url into the Expo Video component, nothing shows up. I am able to download the video onto my computer via this url (I am not able to open it, it "isn't compatible with QuickTime Player) so I think the problem is in the way I am attempting to display the video.

**My question: how do I take this url and display the video in my React Native app?**

some notes:

-when I download the video it is a .mov file

-as shown above, the video is in a protected level on S3

-currently I am using Expo

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm having a similar issue, mp4 hosted on s3 can be downloaded manually, but don't display on expo video component